# How to implement language selector in Oracle APEX App

Tags: oracle, user-interface, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an application with 3 pages. The primary language is English (AppID 123) and the second lang is German (AppID 124). Now I want to implement a selector list which works as language selector.
I know that the item has to set the FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE but I have no idea how and how the select item can show the active language.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First navigate to `shared components -> globalization` and change the `Application Language Derived From` to `Item Preference`.  While you're there take a look at the `Application Primary Language` select list and note down the short codes of the languages you are interested in (e.g. en-us for English United States).

Next create an application item called `FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE`, and a `select list` on the relevant page (or on desktop navigation menu) which displays the languages and returns the language short code.  Then have a plsql process which sets FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE (you could have this as a dynamic action on change if it's on a particular page), e.g.

```
:FSP LANGUAGE PREFERENCE := :P1_ITEM ;
```

This will update your language setting effective from next page load.